# The Cron jobs command does not work in the DirectAdmin control panel

Tags: laravel

I want to run the schedule: run command using the following command
I tried the following command but it did not work

```
/usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null http://xxxxxxx.com/localfiles/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

**Kernel.php**

```php
        protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
   
        $schedule->command('queue:work')->everyMinute();

    }
```

This image belongs to the Direct Admin file manager
[image]

Comment: If it's on the server, you don't want to be using wget, you want to be using php.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler

Answer (score 0):

You can try in server Cron Jobs with-

- - - - - /usr/local/bin/php /home/YOUR_USER_NAME/localfiles/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

And in kernel-

```
$schedule->command('queue:work --tries=3 --delay=2 --stop-when-empty')
->withoutOverlapping()
->runInBackground();
```